# The bean 'exampleService.FeignClientSpecification' could not be registered. Bean already defined and overriding is disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

My feign client class is as below along with the Application class.

```
@FeignClient(name = "ExampleService", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class, url = "http://localhost:8091")
public interface ExampleClient {
  @GetMapping(value = "exampleService/exampleDetails/{id}")
  public List<ExampleDTO> getExampleDetails(@PathVariable(name = "id") final Long id);
}

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.package.example"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package"})
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

In the above code I'm getting the error as given below

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
The bean 'ExampleService.FeignClientSpecification' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.

Action: 
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true
```

First of all, there's only 1 feign client by that name being defined in the project. 
Second I tried giving it a context ID just in case there was a bean with the same name being defined somewhere I must've missed.

```
@FeignClient(contextId = "myExampleService", name="ExampleService", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class, url = "http://localhost:8091")
```

but again it gave me the same error

```
The bean 'myExampleService.FeignClientSpecification' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.
```

Third, I also tried by giving the property in application.properties file for overriding the bean

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding = true
```

but still I'm getting the same error. 
Any reason why I'm getting this issue even though there is only 1 bean with the name available for Spring's app context?

Comment: Hi Guys,
I am also facing same issue. Did anybody have any pointers for same.
Regards,

Comment: @VikramPathania I've added an answer that resolved this for me at least

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Having the same issue at the moment

Comment: @KleoG in case you have more than one feign client in your application, your issue may be solved in the way I lay out in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69715642/9658836)

Answer (score 14):

It might not be the OP's problem since he has only one feign client, but to anyone that got here by googling the same error:

The `name` attribute of the `@FeignClient` annotation works as a unique identifier to the client.
If you want to have multiple feign clients within the same Spring context, each needs to have a unique `name` (or `value`, as [these two attributes are aliases to each other](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/feign/FeignClient.html#value--))

For instance:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/endpoint/path")
@FeignClient(name = "MUST-BE-UNIQUE")
public interface MyClient {
}
```

Comment: that's really weird... There could be more endpoints on single server/backend implemented using interfaces shared with feignclients, which are registered with same serviceId(it is 'name' attribute in fact)  in Eureka/Consul

Comment: @mirec, this is exact issue I'm facing. Our API interface for a single microservice is separated into multiple Feign classes because that is what OpenAPI Generator does by default. So now I have an issue where I can't get service discovery because I need both Feign clients, but have only one service ID for both.

Comment: @EvanBrooks I faced the problem later again and I found solution myself. It is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950859/663432

@FeignClient(name="MY-SERVER", contextId = "THIS-SHOULD-BE-UNIQUE")

Answer (score 6):

That might happen if you have two

```
@EnableFeignClients
```

annotations, with properties that cover one or more feign clients multiple times, for example

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.example.feign.api"})
public class FeignConfigs {
...
}
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class Application {
...
}
```

That was my case. Hope that helps.

Comment: This was my problem, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem.

For me it was a maven issue, it seemed like 2 copies of the same library were being used (not because of a real problem but because maven had "got confused". I had been maven installing local builds of a library).

I resolved the problem by deleting my `C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository` and then reimporting the project

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if you have more than 1 @FeignClients defined with the same name:
[Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/81#issuecomment-444771087)

Giving unique names in my clients fixed it for me

Comment: They can have the same name, but then they have to have a different contextId.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue even though my two FeignClients were completely different. The problem went away once I added `@Component` to both of my FeignClient classes

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting FeignClient interface(ExampleClient) from your test package and run the test case and I hope it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I hab this problem because i had the same contextId in two FeignClients. I made them unique and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the simplest typo in the `application.properties`:

```
examples.api.service.name=example-api
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.examples-api.provider=examples-api
```

As you can see, it's in plural everywhere except for the `service.name`.

After fixing it to be in plural as well, it started working.